# Excel macros editing sheets without displaying

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I've tried to find this answer, but am not really sure what to search for. I have some Excel macros that edit multiple sheets: (e.g. Copy cells from sheet 1, paste onto the end of a list on sheet 2, then put an "X" next to the cells on Sheet 1 and offset to the next row)

My issue is that when I run the macro, it spazzes out, switching the display back and forth between sheets 1 and 2. I can't just cite a specific range (e.g. sheets("Sheet 1").range("c2").dosomething) because the locations are changing. It wouldn't be an issue, but the other users who access the sheet aren't familiar with macros/VBA, and they think something is broken.

In short, the macros do what I want, but it looks really tacky. Is there a way to dynamically work across sheets without changing the displayed sheet/range?

Comment: 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' is a good start.

Comment: `I can't just cite a specific range (e.g. sheets("Sheet 1").range("c2").dosomething) because the locations are changing.` Sounds like a good case to open a new question, post your existing code & some sample data and get some guidance on how to resolve that. Can almost guarantee that with some help & guidance you'll get it sorted out.

Comment: No, it's just that as users alter data, the location of the range to edit is changing because of their input on multiple sheets. Again, I have the macros and issues all worked out, this is purely an aesthetic question. But You've all been most helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can turn off screen updating before performing any actions.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Do your manipulation here

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Depending on how long your macro runs (it will run more quickly with `ScreenUpdating` off, you may want to post something to the status bar `Application.StatusBar = "Doing Step 1"` (put `Application.StatusBar = ""` at the end to clear it), or design a small form with a display box, so your users don't think Excel has totally locked up on them.